# Prevent Object Mapper readerForUpdating overwriting existing data

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I am trying to update value of one object from another using object mapper **readerForUpdating** function. But I have a use case where **I have to update only null values of my existing object** which I am unable to do so. Could anyone please help on this.

**Class:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
class Record {
    private String source;
    private String resource;
}
```

**Record Object:**

```
Record record = new Record();
record.setSource("SourceFromObject");
record.setResource(null);
```

**Object to be Updated:**

```
String incomingJson = "{"source":"SourceFromJson", "resource":"ResourceFromJson"}"
```

**ObjectMapper Logic:**

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
objectMapper.readerForUpdating(record).readValue(incomingJson);
```

Am getting the below output

```
Record: {"source":"SourceFromJson", "resource":"ResourceFromJson"}
```

**But my expected output is**

```
Record: {"source":"SourceFromObject", "resource":"ResourceFromJson"}
```

I tried several suggestions but didn't worked. I have also tried @JsonMerge annotation.

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior for the `ObjectReader` returned by `ObjectMapper.readerForUpdating()`, it would update the given Object with the provided JSON data.

Therefore, you see `"SourceFromJson"` as the value of the `source`.

## Jackson Databinding

If you want to preserve the value of the field `source` intact. Then you can annotate it with [`@JsonIgnore`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#l317).

Or you can apply [`@JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) annotation on the `source` field specifying the [`access`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html#access()) attribute with a value of `JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY` (that would prevent Jackson from writing into this field, but it would be reflected during serialization of the POJO).

## Smart Setters

Another option would be to add validation logic into the setter method, to ensure that each gets updated only if it's `null` (*empty, etc. depending on the type and your requirements*).

Here's how it might look like:

```
@Getter
public static class Record {
    public static final Predicate<String> NULL_OR_EMPTY =
        s -> s == null || s.isEmpty(); // predicate can be reused to validate multiple properties

    private String source;
    private String resource;

    public void setSource(String source) {
        if (NULL_OR_EMPTY.test(this.source)) this.source = source;
    }

    public void setResource(String resource) {
        if (NULL_OR_EMPTY.test(this.resource)) this.resource = resource;
    }
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String incomingJson = """
        {"source":"SourceFromJson", "resource":"ResourceFromJson"}
        """;

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    objectMapper.readerForUpdating(record).readValue(incomingJson);

    System.out.println(record);

    String str = "helloslkhellodjladfjhello";
    System.out.println(countOccurrences(str, "hello"));
}
```

*Output:*

```
Record{source='SourceFromObject', resource='ResourceFromJson'}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander for your answer. But I want the value from json if source is null.

"Record record = new Record();
record.setSource(null);
record.setResource(null);"

Expected output:
Record: {"source":"SourceFromJson", "resource":"ResourceFromJson"}

Basically I want to update only the null fields from the json.

Comment: Any other way to achieve this. Even with other library would also help.

Comment: @Nathan That's doable as well and without introducing a new dependency. See the updated answer.